# Requests 'for header in headers.items():'

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers

I'm working with the python requests library and when making this request.

```
requests.put('https://www.[website].com/api/firebase/setval',headers=headers)
```

I get this error.

```
for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

This is the headers variable:

```
headers={
          'Referer':'https://www.[website].com/',
          'path':str(a)+'/c/'+str(b),
          'val':{
               'b':str(c),
               'g':str(d)
               }
          }
```

Any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: Well, its clearly not, because the error message says its a string.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I didn't include a bit of code where I change it to a string.